# How can I repair a corrupted "find" binary on CentOS?

Tags: centos, find, repair

When I try using "find" on my system, here's what I get:

```
$ find
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I assume the binary got corrupted somehow. How can I repair it? I don't have any other installation of CentOS available to just copy the binary.

Bonus question: is there a way of checking if other binaries are corrupted?

I'm using CentOS 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall findutils. First rpm -e --nodeps findutils and then yum install findutils.

rpm can be used to verify your package Or you can use md5sum and compare the value with a that of a clean install. If you don't have another server you can always install to a different root directory or just extract files from the rpm.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware, that this might be a sign of a rootkit running on your computer. Boot from a clean rescue system and check for malware. Also use `fsck` to see if there are any file system inconsistencies.